# Loopback date value saved as string

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I am working with strongloop and I created a model, which one of its properties is a date value. However, when I access to the model in the explorer (usually http://localhost:3000/explorer/) I noticed that that property is saved as string. I know that I can convert a string into a date object, but I would like to use it directly as date.
Why occurs this?

Thank you!

Comment: You mean saved to db? How would you expect it to be saved? You can parse the string and have a date object?

Comment: I was expecting to save it as date object. Now I understood that you can not save Date object into JSON file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the stored data was coming via the API and so was in JSON notation before?

JSON does not know the date object, so dates are often strings. Sadly there is no common standard how this date string is formatted.

What you could do in this case is to put a `setter` on your date field at the model to convert it:

```
MyModel.setter['myDateField'] = function(value) {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    // your conversion
  }
  return value;
};
```